# Centralized data access or variables

Tags: c, database, linux, distributed-computing

I'm trying to find a way to access a centralized database for both retrieval and update.

the following is what I'm looking for,

Server 1 has this variable for example
int counter;

Server 2 will be interacting with the user, and will increase the counter whenever the user uses the service, until a certain threshold is reached. when this threshold is reached then server 2 will start rejecting the user access.

Also, the user will be able to use multiple servers (like server 2) from multiple locations and each time the user accesses the access any server the counter will be increased.

I tried google but it's hard to search for something without a name.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to designing this is to do sharding by user - i.e. split the users between your servers depending on the ID of the user. That is, if you have 10 servers, then users with ID's ending with 2 would have all of their data stored on server 2, and so on. This assumes that user ID's are distributed uniformly.

One other approach is to shard the users by location - if you have servers in Asia vs Europe, for example. You'd need a property in the User record that tells you where the user is located; based on that, you'll know which server to route them to.

Ultimately, all of these design options have a concept of "where does the master record for a user reside?" Each of these approaches attempts to definitively answer this question.

A different category of approaches has to do with multi-master replication, which is supported by some database vendors; this approach does not scale as well (i.e. it's hard to get it to scale to 20 servers), but you might want to look into it, too.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of using a hashing algorithm to distribute users but I'm not how to handle of one server goes down then the user that handled by server 10 will be handled by 9. using master DB and a replication looks good here.